what's the best way to render a ambient occlusion pass?
what's the best way to render a Ambient Occlusion pass without a backdrop so the background will be white instead of transparent?

In the Render properties tab under Film you could enable Transparent, which would give you a matte for the bg, then if you have the AO pass enabled as well then you can just invert the BG matte and Add that to the AO pass, with the output clamped. That would give you what you're describing. Though I'm not sure I fully understande the question.

how would you invert the BG matte

With an Invert Color node in the compositor.

To combine the transparent background to the ambient occlusion pass is to use the invert color to invert the Alpha pass make sure you click RGB and ALPHA boxes and then use the Alpha Over to combine the Alpha and the AO pass. I included a picture of the node tree

